# Почему скрипт PHP в фоновом режиме закрывается через минуту?

Tags: php, ubuntu, веб-программирование, bash, unix

Скрипт запускаю из под консоли в Debian так: `php socket.php >>output.txt 2>&1 &`
, в нутри скрипта прописано `set_time_limit(0);`.
Скрипт зациклен. Скрипт работает примерно минуту и завершает процесс.
Однажды удалось в консоли увидеть надпись: `[+1] Exit 1 php socket.php >>output.txt 2>&1 &`

Как сделать, чтобы скрипт работал в фоне "постоянно"?

**UPDT:**
Суть скрипта, создает и прослушивает сокет. В зависимости от информации которая попадает в сокет, делает замеры и отправляет ответы.

Comment: `set_time_limit(0);` на cli-скрипты не влияет. вылетает по разным причинам, начиная от ошибки в скрипте и кончая тем, что его прибивает OOM-киллер. включите на максимум вывод ошибок для начала. ну и скрипт неплохо бы видеть тут.

Comment: Дело в том, что без фонового режима скрипт работает долго. Как бы вся ситуация именно в фоновом режиме

Comment: stdin / stdout использует?

Comment: внутри скрипта - нет

Comment: [терминальный мультиплексор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80)